# How to create a link in a XSL to another XSL to generate different outputs?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recetas.xsl"?>
<libro>
<receta>
<nombre>Escaldón</nombre>
<procedencia>Tenerife</procedencia>
<imagen>escaldon.jpg</imagen>
<ingredientes>
<ingrediente>
<nombreIngrediente>gofio</nombreIngrediente>
<cantidad>150g</cantidad>
<valorEnergetico>399 kcal</valorEnergetico>
<grasa>3.72 g</grasa>
<hidratos>122.355 g</hidratos>
<fibra>2.805 g</fibra>
<proteinas>16.2 g</proteinas>
<colesterol>0.000135 mg</colesterol>
</ingrediente>
<ingrediente>
<nombreIngrediente>caldo</nombreIngrediente>
<cantidad>800 ml</cantidad>
<valorEnergetico>225 kcal</valorEnergetico>
<grasa>0.6 g</grasa>
<hidratos>27.47 g</hidratos>
<fibra>0.2 g</fibra>
<proteinas>17 g</proteinas>
<colesterol>0.000015 mg</colesterol>
</ingrediente>
<ingrediente>
<nombreIngrediente>costillas de cerdo desmenuzadas</nombreIngrediente>
<cantidad>2</cantidad>
<valorEnergetico>781 kcal</valorEnergetico>
<grasa>19.6 g</grasa>
<hidratos>107.82 g</hidratos>
<fibra>27.2 g</fibra>
<proteinas>47 g</proteinas>
<colesterol>0.0011</colesterol>
</ingrediente>
</ingredientes>
<preparacion>
<paso>Poner los ingredientes troceados en un bol o recipiente de barro o cerámica preferiblemente</paso>
<paso>Añadir el caldo y luego el gofio.</paso>
<paso>Mezclar hasta lograr una mezcla homogénea.</paso>
</preparacion>
</receta>
</libro>`
```

and this XSL:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Receta</th>
<th>ingredientes</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="libro/receta/ingredientes/ingrediente">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="nombreIngrediente"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="fibra"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>`
```

And how to achieve to link another xsl like an hyperlink in html with `<a href="">` label but in xslt to for example:

```
<td><a href="other.xsl">LINK</a></td>
```

and then redirection to another xsl only having 1 XML, or Must I create another XML? and if it would be so, What could I do to link it and in the same XHTML to differents output?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the "link" to the other XSL to do?  What XML does it apply to?  I believe you misunderstand how XSL works.  You will need to show the "other" XSL file and the output you expect from such a transformation.

Comment: I want the another XSL creates another page when I click in the link in my XML index page.

Comment: That's not how it would work.  The link would be to another XML file which would have its own `<?xml-stylesheet...>` instruction at the top.

Comment: If you link to an XSLT stylesheet you tell the browser to load that XSLT stylesheet when someone follows the link, you don't tell the browser to apply that stylesheet to another or the same XML as before. If you are restricted to client-side, in browser XSLT all you could do is to write Javascript code applying another XSLT. A cleaner solution would be to implement the XSLT transformation on the server and then link to a server page that applies the XSLT and returns the HTML to the browser.